# I'm trying to retrieve the serial number of a hard drive or a battery tag

Tags: c++, windows, createfile, deviceiocontrol

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <WinIoCtl.h>
#include <Winbase.h>

typedef struct _MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA {  
      ULONG SerialNumberLength;
      ULONG Result;
      ULONG Retreived;
      DWORD SerialNumberData[];
} MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA, *PMEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA;  // the structure of IOCTL_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA 

int main() {
    HANDLE hard;
    bool result;
    MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA  val;  
    char buf[sizeof(MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA)];
    MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA * p = (MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA *) buf;

    hard = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:", 0, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    result = DeviceIoControl(hard, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER,    NULL, 0, buf, sizeof buf, 0, NULL);

   if (hard == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
       printf("Terminal error : invalid handle value \n");

   printf("valeur Handle : %c \n", hard);
   printf("valeur retour :    %d \n", result);
   printf("valeur serial : %d \n",    p->SerialNumberData);     
   printf("valeur longeur num serie : %d \n",    p->SerialNumberLength); 

   CloseHandle(hard); // free the Handle    
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile and execute this piece of code, I get following result:

> ```
> valeur Handle : D
> valeur retour : 0
> valeur serial : 15530164     
> valeur longeur num serie : -858993460
> ```

Comment: 1) Indent your code correctly. Currently it is - unreadable. 2) Copy the output that you get, into the question, rather than providing images to it. 3) We can't understand your output anyway, provide it in English. 4) Didn't you look at the question preview? It is there, for a reason.

Comment: If you use C++ stream I/O you'll have fewer problems with types.

Comment: @molbdnilo: You cannot send device IO control codes using C++ I/O streams. Often a good suggestion, but certainly not in this case.

Comment: @IInspectable I was referring to the `printf`s.

Comment: @IInspectable  I think the problem is in  the pointer  ,the serial number is returned but the size of serial not

Comment: Not at all, the problem is that not a single one of your `printf` calls is correct.

Comment: @IInspectable  but if it was then i will get no result on terminal no???

Comment: I'll try with i\o stream and see

Comment: Undefined behavior makes no promises. Anything can happen, including to work as intended. It doesn't here, and you're lucky to be on an architecture, that has insanely relaxed alignment restrictions. That type of bug explodes in your face on many architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reading some documentation.

1. Almost all your `printf`s use the wrong format string.
2. Your structure is not the structure that `DeviceIoControl` returns for `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER`.
3. If `lpOverlapped` is `NULL`, `lpBytesReturned` cannot be `NULL`.
4. `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER` retrieves the serial number of a *USB device*.
5. The return value zero from `DeviceIoControl` indicates failure.

Comment: hhmmm okk,i see now ,thnx for the answer